# Azure frontdoor: The request URI is invalid

Tags: azure, subdomain, azure-front-door

I am trying to use azure frontdoor to access a nginx running in a kubernetes cluster.

I can reach the nginx instance on the public IP, but when trying trough azure front door i get a "The request URI is invalid" error.

[image]

The health probes also seem to be failing, even though i did not change any settings and can access nginx via the public IP.

Looking at the time where the backend is availible, i don't see any request to the backend:
[image]

I have setup my forwarding rules like this:
[image]

EDIT:

It seems that i get a different error message when visiting www.1234h.azurefd.net as opposed to 1234h.azurefd.net (no www).

no www gives a "The request URI is invalid" while the one with www gives "Our services aren't available right now".

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was an issue in azure.

A partial fix was:

- wait for a couple of hours
- Add a web app to the backend, and change routing rules
- After about 10 minutes the http domain started working (still no https)
- Changing the forward rule back to kubernetes (with no changes to the backend) gave http access.

I guess the steps are not needed, but the issue was resolved around the same time i did the steps.

If i get https access without changing any settings i will report back to confirm if this were a problem in azure and not with my settings.

Other symptoms that lead me to believe this was an azure issue:

- There were a few hours were my connection attemps were not registered in the metrics
- After the http magically worked, i see my request at the backend graph mathing the frontend requests
- Logging does not work properly (i see  "Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AzureActivity'" even though the column are shown in the tables overview)

EDIT:
Https started working while i wrote this answer.
Again, i did not change anything.

Comment: Did you ever work out what happened here? Sounds mostly like a propagation issue? Thanks

Comment: yes, i think it is a propogation issue.
Being more experienced with azure at this time, i see random propogation issues from time to time.
I have seen other propogation issues with azure front door as well.

When i enroll a new domain, i start by pointing afdverify.example.com to afdverify.myfrontdoor.azurefd.com, and set up azure frontdoor a day before i point example.com to myfrontdoor.azurefd.net.

You can test your AFD settings (and SSL) by changing your host file before you change the DNS

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "The request URI is invalid" only when hitting FD via HTTPS. It worked fine for HTTP.

My FD routing rule was configured as such:

[image]

But given that I don't care about HTTP, I just configured my app service to be "HTTPS only" and things started working:

[image]